# Evaluate result of a Detection algorithm based on the object's shape as Ground truth

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model-evaluation, image-processing, object-detection

I'm working on project where i have to detect small colored cars driving on rails from static camera (**Bird's Eye-view see below image**)

[image]

The algorithm in short outputs first a mask image with only the candidate target and then a bouding box is calculated.

To in order to evaluate the detection, a traditional principle is to measure the precision which is calculated based on IOU (intersection over union) and number of True and False positives (TP and FP)

To do that, i simply need ground truth bounding boxes which means i need to label over 50 videos (around 20000 frames) which is really exhausted and time consuming.

So alternatively, is it considered as an acceptable evaluation, if i do the evaluation based on the shape of my target object? which means i calculate how much the segmented object in the mask-image looks like a rectangle?. And so, if the segmented and detected object is 90% a rectangle, then i consider this as an acceptable detection (TP) and if its under 50% a rectangle, it is considered as a false positive.

**I know this kind of evaluation does not give me info about the position, and that is why i'm asking if it can still yet be considered as a valid evaluation ?**

Comment: a "valid evaluation" is whatever you can convince people is valid. you might have a very hard time convincing the research community this is a reasonable or "valid", but maybe the only person you want to convince is your manager.

Comment: @shimao so impressive. Thanks dude!